# Python/Django. Difference between Decimal calculation local and server

Tags: python, django, decimal

We use Decimal number to store values.
I have simple formula: **price * quantity * percent / 100**

```
def round_value(value):
    x = math.floor(value)
    if (value - x) < .50:
        return x
    else:
        return math.ceil(value)

def calculate_reward(price, quantity, percent):
    return round_value(price * quantity * percent / 100*)
```

So in my case i have values:

```
calculate_reward(Decimal(77), 2, 87)
```

On local machine i have: 134

On server: 130

I dont have even a clue why such behavior on the server.
Does anyone know?

Comment: How do you callculate this on the server/client?

Comment: I use "calculate_reward" function